# Como fazer com que outros usuário consigam acessar meu banco MySQL com Python?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa com a biblioteca mysql-connector-python e queria que outros usuários pudessem acessar a ela, pois quando inicio o programa em outra máquina aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Dirsoo/PycharmProjects/Sistema/Sistema.py", line 11, in <module>
database='sistema_cadastro_produtos'
File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 265, in connect
return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 104, in __init__
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 966, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 288, in _open_connection
self._socket.open_connection()
File "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 611, in open_connection
errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente)
```

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão aqui não é exatamente de Python.

O problema é que o acesso está sendo feito para `localhost:3306`. Localhost é o endereço de *loopback*, em outras palavras, é a propria máquina.

Acredito que no programa `C:/Users/Dirsoo/PycharmProjects/Sistema/Sistema.py` linha 11, você tenha a string de conexão.

Altere de `loopback` para o endereço IP da máquina onde está o banco de dados ou o FQDN (full qualified domain name) - ex.: 192.168.1.1 ou url.do.banco.com.br

Espero que a dica ajude.